# How Do I Use a Javascript Regex Extraction Script to Simply Remove the String?

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I am trying to remove a line of text across all posts on a Wordpress site. The line involves dates and has no special class, I can only think of using regular expressions. Using the txt2re.com tool I was able to get the following Javascript:

```
<script language=javascript>
      var txt='<p>Rodney Johnson | Monday, April 14, 2014 >></p>';

      var re1='(<[^>]+>)';  // Tag 1
      var re2='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';  // Word 1
      var re3='(\\s+)'; // White Space 1
      var re4='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';  // Word 2
      var re5='(\\s+)'; // White Space 2
      var re6='(.)';    // Any Single Character 1
      var re7='(\\s+)'; // White Space 3
      var re8='((?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|Tues|Thur|Thurs|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat))'; // Day Of Week 1
      var re9='(.)';    // Any Single Character 2
      var re10='(\\s+)';    // White Space 4
      var re11='((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Sept|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))';   // Month 1
      var re12='(\\s+)';    // White Space 5
      var re13='((?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1})))(?![\\d])';    // Day 1
      var re14='(.)';   // Any Single Character 3
      var re15='(\\s+)';    // White Space 6
      var re16='((?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])';  // Year 1
      var re17='(\\s+)';    // White Space 7
      var re18='(.)';   // Any Single Character 4
      var re19='(.)';   // Any Single Character 5
      var re20='(<[^>]+>)'; // Tag 2

      var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13+re14+re15+re16+re17+re18+re19+re20,["i"]);
      var m = p.exec(txt);
      if (m != null)
      {
          var tag1=m[1];
          var word1=m[2];
          var ws1=m[3];
          var word2=m[4];
          var ws2=m[5];
          var c1=m[6];
          var ws3=m[7];
          var dayofweek1=m[8];
          var c2=m[9];
          var ws4=m[10];
          var month1=m[11];
          var ws5=m[12];
          var day1=m[13];
          var c3=m[14];
          var ws6=m[15];
          var year1=m[16];
          var ws7=m[17];
          var c4=m[18];
          var c5=m[19];
          var tag2=m[20];
          document.write("("+tag1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+word1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+word2.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws2.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+c1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws3.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+dayofweek1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+c2.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws4.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+month1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws5.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+day1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+c3.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws6.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+year1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+ws7.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+c4.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+c5.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"("+tag2.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
      }
    </script>
```

I can insert this into Wordpress dynamically, but how would I get this script to simply remove the specific string being extracted?

I am unable to find a regex generator that could spit out a single expression for this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I like to use www.regexr.com to test/build regex's. You can put your sentence into the text box and start trying things out until you have a regular expression that matches as you'd expect. Additionally the site has a reference of different regex keywords and syntax. It's a great utility and a nice place to develop working regular expressions.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use Javascript to do this. Better would be just to comment out the line of your theme's php file that generates this text.

Comment: The thing is that this line is part of a previous import, it is not generated by anything at this point. Also, I tried regexr but could not figure it out after a while, I do not really want to learn regex at the moment, so looking for a different solution. (I actually tried to simply add the vars consecutively, but any time there would be two parentheses adjacent, say: (<[^>]+>)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))  it said it was not valid.. if theres a way around this I'd love to hear it too.)